# Display the variable with the highest value

Tags: php

I have four variables these variables are textfields.

I want to output the one with the highest value and display its value and display its name.

```
<?php 
 $a = array($_SESSION['musicM'], $_SESSION['preach'],$_SESSION['techno'],$_SESSION['profess']); 
 $value = min($a);
 $name = $_POST['$value'];  
    print_r ($value);
    print_r($name);

    ?>
```

Comment: Replace `min()` with `max()`?

Comment: That'll never work. min returns the smallest **VALUE**. you're then trying to (badly/incorrectly) use that value as a KEY. Basic PHP 101: `'`-quoted strings do **NOT** interpolate variables, therefore you're looking for a $_POST key whose name is `$`, `v`, `a`, etc...

Answer (score 0):

this might help you

```
 $a = array($_SESSION['musicM'], $_SESSION['preach'],$_SESSION['techno'],$_SESSION['profess']); 
 $value = max($a);
```

and get the corresponding key

```
$key = array_search($value, $array);
```

Comment: How do I then display the name of the max value